# Parsing a statement and Adding Paranthesis to them

Tags: parsing, flex-lexer, yacc, lex, bisonc++

I am trying to parse logical BNF statements , and trying to apply paranthesis to them.

**For example:**
I am trying to parse a statement ***a=>b<=>c&d*** as ***((a)=>(b))<=>((c)&(d))***, and similar statements as well.

**Problem Facing:** Some of the statements are working fine, and while some are not. The example provided above is not working and the solution is printing as ((c)&(d))<=>((c)&(d)) The second expr seems to be overriding the first one.

**Conditions that are working:** While other simple examples like a<=>b , a|(b&c) are working fine.

I think I have made some basic error in my code, which I cannot figure out.

Here is my code

lex file

```
letters [a-zA-Z]
identifier {letters}+
operator (?:<=>|=>|\||&|!)
separator [\(\)]    

%%
{identifier} {
    yylval.s = strdup(yytext);
    return IDENTIFIER; }
{operator} { return *yytext; }
{separator} { return *yytext; }
[\n] { return *yytext; }
%%
```

yacc file

```
%start program
%union  {char* s;}
%type <s> program expr IDENTIFIER
%token IDENTIFIER
%left '<=>'
%left '=>'
%left '|' 
%left '&'
%right '!'
%left '(' ')'

%%
program : expr '\n'     
          { 
            cout<<$$;
            exit(0);
          }
     ;
    
expr : IDENTIFIER  {  
        cout<<" Atom ";
        cout<<$1<<endl;
        string s1 = string($1);
        cout<<$$<<endl;
        
    }
     | expr '<=>' expr   {
        cout<<"Inside <=>\n";
        string s1 = string($1); 
        string s2 = string($3); 
        string s3 = "(" + s1 +")" +"<=>"+"(" + s2 +")";
        $$ = (char *    )s3.c_str();
        cout<<s3<<endl;
     }
     | expr '=>' expr   {
        cout<<"Inside =>\n";
        string s1 = string($1);
        string s2 = string($3); 
        string s3 = "(" + s1 +")" +"=>"+"(" + s2 +")";
        $$ = (char *)s3.c_str();
        cout<<$$<<endl;
     }
     | expr '|' expr    { 
 
        cout<<"Inside |\n";
        string s1 = string($1);
        string s2 = string($3); 
        string s3 = "(" + s1 +")" +"|"+"(" + s2 +")";
        $$ = (char *)s3.c_str();
        cout<<$$<<endl;
     }
     | expr '&' expr    {

        cout<<"Inside &\n";
        string s1 = string($1);
        string s2 = string($3); 
        string s3 = "(" + s1 +")" +"&"+"(" + s2 +")";
        $$ = (char *)s3.c_str();
        cout<<$$<<endl;
     }
     | '!' expr {      

        cout<<"Inside !\n"; 
        string s1 = string($2);
        cout<<s1<<endl;
        string s2 = "!" + s1;
        $$ = (char *)s2.c_str();
        cout<<$$<<endl;
     }
     | '(' expr ')'         {  $$ = $2; cout<<"INSIDE BRACKETS"; }
     ;
%%
```

Please let me know the mistake I have made.

Thank you

Comment: You have lots of dangling pointers, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: @ChrisDodd can you help on how to proceed? I am coming back to yacc and lex after 3 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem you have is that you save the pointer returned by `string::c_str()` on the yacc value stack, but after the action finishes and the `string` object is destroyed, that pointer is no longer valid.

To fix this you need to either not use `std::string` at all, or change your `%union` to be `{ std::string *s; }` (instead of `char *`).  In either case you have issues with memory leaks.  If you are using Linux, the former is pretty easy.  Your actions would become something like:

```
     | expr '<=>' expr   {
        cout<<"Inside <=>\n";
        asprintf(&$$, "(%s)<=>(%s)", $1, $3);
        cout<<$$<<endl;
        free($1);
        free($3);
     }
```

for the latter, the action would look like:

```
     | expr '<=>' expr   {
        cout<<"Inside <=>\n";
        $$ = new string("(" + *$1 +")" +"<=>"+"(" + *$2 +")");
        cout<<$$<<endl;
        delete $1;
        delete $3;
     }
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a doubt. If I do the former part , , will the parser again check for '(' expr ')' rule? If not how to do it?

Comment: No the parser is actually not checking it again. That's why I asked you. I would want it to check the rules again. Atleast I want the parser to check expr <=> expr rule again. But it is not checking.

Comment: For that rule, you could have just `'(' expr ')' { $$ = $2; }`, which would effectively remove the parens.  Or you could put them back with `{ asprintf(&$$, "(%s)", $2); free($2); }`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "checking" -- the parser doesn't check anything; it parses the input based on the rules.

Comment: Sorry, Let me rephrase my question. If there is a rule expr : expr '=>' expr , {$$ = '(' + $1 + ')'} and there is another rule '(' expr ')' { $$ = $2; }, For the input a=>b,will there be a possibility  for the parser to use the rule 2, for the output of rule 1

Comment: The rules are only used to parse input.  Only if you take the output and redirect to another run of the parser (perhaps saving the output in a file and then running again with that file) would that happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238191/discussion-between-no-reveal-name-and-chris-dodd).